# Restart rsyslog after NTP time sync

Tags: rsyslog, ntpd

I want to ensure that the logs written, have the correct timestamp.

So, when `ntpd` completes the sync (`ntpq -c rv` displays `sync_ntp`), I want to restart `rsyslogd`. But I am not finding any hooks/config to do this!

Also, I am not sure, if I should be doing this in `ntpd` or `rsyslog` config (if possible)?

Any help, or workarounds to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that? Why wouldn't `rsyslog` just begin using the new time after it had been set?

Comment: After `ntpd` synced the time, I was still seeing that the logs in `/var/log/syslog` was showing older timestamps, and `rsyslogd` restart fixed it. But, I wanted to do it automatically, rather than manually. Or, I'm not sure if I'm missing some config in `rsyslogd`!